# DAX, PowerBI: Calculated column with annual max value from other calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

[image: Sample part of the table]

I have a calculated table with dates from calendar table, [Rok] is Year([Data]), KB... columns are just values for this and last 3 years for that day, Avg KB t-3 is calculated column with average value from last 3 years.

I need to add a calculated column with MAX of [Avg KB t-3] for each Rok.

It sounds very easy, yet I've tried many different approaches and failed.

Please enlighten me with your ideas, for I have lost :)

Comment: Let's consider it other way:
I have 3 measures which are calculating number of transactions for certain day  one, two and three years ago. I also have a measure which is calculating Average of those three measures for each day. 
What I still can't figure out is a measure which will calculate this Average value for given period and for every day in this period return MAX value of Average in this period. For ex: let's say that i have selected dates March, 26th to May, 31st and I have a measure returning Average of 3 years for each day and max Avg for those days will be X; now I need this X.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
MaxAverage = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[Avg KB t-3]);FILTER('YourTable';'YourTable'[Rok] = EARLIER('YourTable'[Rok])))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I took a different approach and ended up with this:

```
MaxAVG = 
VAR tabela =
CALCULATETABLE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        DATESBETWEEN('Calendar Table'[Data]; [Start]; [Koniec]);
        "Avg"; [AvgKB]
    );
    ALLEXCEPT(
        'WSF Baza';
        'WSF Baza'[Poziom]
    )
)
RETURN
IF(
    OR(
        MAX('Calendar Table'[Data]) < [Start];
        MAX('Calendar Table'[Data]) > [Koniec]
    );
    BLANK();
    MAXX(tabela;[Avg])
)
```

First I'm creating a "virtual" table containing all dates in a period I'm interested in and add the column with calculated Average of last 3 years for certain day. 'WSF Baza'[Poziom] is the parameter I want to be able to filter my data by.

Then by IF statement I narrow my results only to dates I'm interested in and for each date in this period I return MAX of Average values in whole period.